# How to turn off log4j warnings?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm running a Java app that depends on a few libraries (Axis2) which use log4j.  I don't use log4j and don't have any configuration file.  I'd like to just completely disable log4j and squelch any and all warnings that it spits out.  Right now, when I run my app, when I call one of the library's methods, I see:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Is there some static log4j disable method I can call? I tried Logger.getRootLogger().removeAllAppenders(); and this did not work (I still see the warnings).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could try

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: This works as long as the setLevel call fires before the first log message.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Just had to add the log4j-x-x.jar to the Classpath, works great.

Answer (score 8):

The Apache libraries are horribly user-unfriendly. If I wanted logging, I would have turned it on myself. To turn the logging off:

1. Add log4j-1.2.xxx.jar to your CLASSPATH.
2. Then add the following to your Java code before the logging starts:

   org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);

Comment: Use a more recent version of Log4J, you might get Log4Shell with older versions

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import org.apache.log4j.Level, not the java.util.logging.Level, otherwise you get an error saying "The method setLevel(Level) in the type Category is not applicable for the arguments (Level)"

Comment: This isn't a complete answer and should have provided more detail or been left as a comment.