# log4j warning issue - apache commons

Tags: java, log4j, apache-commons

I'm using apache commons library and log4j.
I have an xml configuration file and a log4j.properties files. I want to specify my log4j properties path inside my xml configuration file.
To load my settings i do:

```
//Loading my xml file
this.config = new XMLConfiguration(this.xmlFileName);
```

At this moment the following warnings are raised:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

However i haven't yet called any log4j object. Once i have read the xml file i can successfully work with my log4j instance.
Is there any way to remove those warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4J outputs this error when a logger is created, but no appender(s) is(are) defined.
In practice this error occurs when a logger is created before log4j is initialized.

You say you haven't called any log4j object. But in the error message you see that `org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils` creates a logger object (see line [66](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/xref/org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationUtils.html)).

You could turn it off before initialization, see [How to turn off log4j warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849887/how-to-turn-off-log4j-warnings)

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

There should be no need to turn it on again since the initialization sets normally the log level of the root logger.

Comment: Ok, are there any way to disable LOG inside the 'org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils' or configure my log4j properties insied my xml configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Check if the log4j.properties file is in the classpath

This link might be useful:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/63230/open-source/log-log-WARN-No-appenders

Comment: I don't want insert my log4j.properties in the classpath, because it is placed external to  the jar and in another directory. I want load it at run-time, using the path specified in my application configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least set the appender and the logger level for the root logger in the loaded log4j configuration file. Otherwise , you will see this warning message.

Example of setting the appender and logger level for the root logger:

```
#Set root logger 's level and its appender to an appender called CONSOLE which is defined below.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE

#Set the behavior of the CONSOLE appender 
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my issue with this workaround:

```
//Disable log level
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Now i can read my xml configuration file without WARNINGS.
After set log level:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Comment: Isn't this the solution I suggested in my comment under my post?