# Is there a way not to print the log4j warn messages?

Tags: java, log4j

I get the following:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.test.Books).  
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I do not want to print these messages, regardless to whether if my log4j configuration is correct or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off log4j warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849887/how-to-turn-off-log4j-warnings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off the warnings try:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

And as said in the comment it might be better using the log4j.xml here is a nice link on its format and a few examples too: http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat

Reference:

- [How to turn off log4j warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849887/how-to-turn-off-log4j-warnings)

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend to do this using `log4j.xml` configuration file.

Comment: @AlexR Thank you added link to the log4j.xml format which also has a few examples and nice explanations

Comment: What I tried at first is to use -Dlog4j.configuration=file:<PATH_TO_LOG4J_XML_FILE>. I did manage to use log4j, but I still saw these warnings, so I asked this question. Does anyone have a clue why it acts like this?

Comment: @zaske Maybe see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685510/log4j-warning-while-initializing and http://activemq.apache.org/log4j-warn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger.html